# Download file from Blob URL with Python

Tags: python, download, blob, urllib

I wish to have my Python script download the *Master data (Download, XLSX)* Excel file from this [Frankfurt stock exchange webpage](http://www.xetra.com/xetra-en/instruments/etf-exchange-traded-funds/list-of-tradable-etfs).

When to retrieve it with `urrlib` and `wget`, it turns out that the URL leads to a *Blob*  and the file downloaded is only 289 bytes and unreadable.

> http://www.xetra.com/blob/1193366/b2f210876702b8e08e40b8ecb769a02e/data/All-tradable-ETFs-ETCs-and-ETNs.xlsx

I'm entirely unfamiliar with Blobs and have these questions:

- Can the file "behind the Blob" be successfully retrieved using Python?
- If so, is it necessary to uncover the "true" URL behind the Blob – if there is such a thing – and how? My concern here is that the link above won't be static but actually change often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That 289 byte long thing might be a HTML code for `403 forbidden` page. This happen because the server is smart and rejects if your code does not specify a user agent.

**Python 3**

```
# python3
import urllib.request as request

url = 'http://www.xetra.com/blob/1193366/b2f210876702b8e08e40b8ecb769a02e/data/All-tradable-ETFs-ETCs-and-ETNs.xlsx'
# fake user agent of Safari
fake_useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25'
r = request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': fake_useragent})
f = request.urlopen(r)

# print or write
print(f.read())
```

**Python 2**

```
# python2
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.xetra.com/blob/1193366/b2f210876702b8e08e40b8ecb769a02e/data/All-tradable-ETFs-ETCs-and-ETNs.xlsx'
# fake user agent of safari
fake_useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25'

r = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': fake_useragent})
f = urllib2.urlopen(r)

print(f.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to be able to download the file to disk (preferably while being able to overwrite), not just `read` it.

Comment: That is an example. Once you `f.read()`, you can write it into another file. The point is using a fake agent to retrieve an excel file. After then, it is the same as file manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url='http://www.xetra.com/xetra-en/instruments/etf-exchange-traded-funds/list-of-tradable-etfs'
html=requests.get(url)
page=BeautifulSoup(html.content)
reg=re.compile('Master data')
find=page.find('span',text=reg)  #find the file url
file_url='http://www.xetra.com'+find.parent['href']
file=requests.get(file_url)
with open(r'C:\\Users\user\Downloads\file.xlsx','wb') as ff:
    ff.write(file.content)
```

recommend requests and BeautifulSoup,both good lib

Comment: I'm considering this solution. Will it be more robust in case the "blob URL" changes? (Do they?)

Comment: of course,if the framework of the page not change@Winterflags

Comment: It seems that this doesn't work if the url is like "blob:https://www.blabla.com....". 
Any idea how to handle this? 
Also, why did you pass "span" as an argument to page.find("span", text=reg) ?

Answer (score 0):

for me, the target download url is like:
blob:https://jdc.xxxx.com/2c21275b-c1ef-487a-a378-1672cd2d0760

i tried to write the original response in local xlsx, and found it was working.

```
import requests
        
r = requests.post(r'http://jdc.xxxx.com/rawreq/api/handler/desktop/export-rat-view?flag=jdc',json=data,headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
file_name = 'file_name.xlsx'
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(100000):
        f.write(chunk)
```